# Amending date in a file path using python

Tags: python, string, concatenation, filepath

How do I make the filepath dynamic. I have to pick info from 7 spreadsheets and I  have to just daily change the dates in these file paths. How can i declare the date and call the date in a string.

date = 20200607

filepath = HKTR Report\06. June**20200605**\Summary006T-CTRD2603-FX-**20200605**.csv"

The two dates in the file path have to be replaced with date declared making the filepath dynamic. 
Kindly assist.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The path you have listed is peculiar in that it contains star characters which are not usually used in pathnames.

That said, try using this code:

```
from datetime import date

    d = date.today()
    date_str = d.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    print(date_str)

    filepath = f'HKTR Report\\06. June**{date_str}**\\Summary006T-CTRD2603-FX-{date_str}.csv'

    print(filepath)
```

which generates this output:

```
20200608
HKTR Report\06. June**20200608**\Summary006T-CTRD2603-FX-20200608.csv
```